# TimedCrowdsale.sol does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, crowdsale

I found success in deploying Crowdsale.sol on ropsten testnet but I am finding trouble with TimedCrowdsale.sol

I am using OpenZeppelin contracts of TimedCrowdsale.sol, SafeMath.sol, Crowdsale.sol, ERC20.sol and ERC20Basic.sol

I am able to compile TimedCrowdsale.sol.

The error message is "This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created."

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

browser/TimedCrowdsale.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import './SafeMath.sol';
import './Crowdsale.sol';


/**
 * @title TimedCrowdsale
 * @dev Crowdsale accepting contributions only within a time frame.
 */
contract TimedCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  uint256 public openingTime;
  uint256 public closingTime;

  /**
   * @dev Reverts if not in crowdsale time range.
   */
  modifier onlyWhileOpen {
    // solium-disable-next-line security/no-block-members
    require(block.timestamp >= openingTime && block.timestamp <= closingTime);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Constructor, takes crowdsale opening and closing times.
   * @param _openingTime Crowdsale opening time
   * @param _closingTime Crowdsale closing time
   */
  constructor(uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime) public {
    // solium-disable-next-line security/no-block-members
    require(_openingTime >= block.timestamp);
    require(_closingTime >= _openingTime);

    openingTime = _openingTime;
    closingTime = _closingTime;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Checks whether the period in which the crowdsale is open has already elapsed.
   * @return Whether crowdsale period has elapsed
   */
  function hasClosed() public view returns (bool) {
    // solium-disable-next-line security/no-block-members
    return block.timestamp > closingTime;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Extend parent behavior requiring to be within contributing period
   * @param _beneficiary Token purchaser
   * @param _weiAmount Amount of wei contributed
   */
  function _preValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
    onlyWhileOpen
  {
    super._preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, _weiAmount);
  }

}
```

browser/SafeMath.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {

  /**
  * @dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.
  */
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    // uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return a / b;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Subtracts two numbers, throws on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
  */
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}
```

browser/Crowdsale.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import './ERC20.sol';
import './SafeMath.sol';

/**
 * @title Crowdsale
 * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale,
 * allowing investors to purchase tokens with ether. This contract implements
 * such functionality in its most fundamental form and can be extended to provide additional
 * functionality and/or custom behavior.
 * The external interface represents the basic interface for purchasing tokens, and conform
 * the base architecture for crowdsales. They are *not* intended to be modified / overriden.
 * The internal interface conforms the extensible and modifiable surface of crowdsales. Override
 * the methods to add functionality. Consider using 'super' where appropiate to concatenate
 * behavior.
 */

contract Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // The token being sold
  ERC20 public token;

  // Address where funds are collected
  address public wallet;

  // How many token units a buyer gets per wei
  uint256 public rate;

  // Amount of wei raised
  uint256 public weiRaised;

  /**
   * Event for token purchase logging
   * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
   * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
   * @param value weis paid for purchase
   * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
   */
  event TokenPurchase(
    address indexed purchaser,
    address indexed beneficiary,
    uint256 value,
    uint256 amount
  );

  /**
   * @param _rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
   * @param _wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
   * @param _token Address of the token being sold
   */
  constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, ERC20 _token) public {
    require(_rate > 0);
    require(_wallet != address(0));
    require(_token != address(0));

    rate = _rate;
    wallet = _wallet;
    token = _token;
  }

  // -----------------------------------------
  // Crowdsale external interface
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev fallback function ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   */
  function () external payable {
    buyTokens(msg.sender);
  }

  /**
   * @dev low level token purchase ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   */
  function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable {

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    _preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    _processPurchase(_beneficiary, tokens);
    emit TokenPurchase(
      msg.sender,
      _beneficiary,
      weiAmount,
      tokens
    );

    _updatePurchasingState(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

    _forwardFunds();
    _postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
  }

  // -----------------------------------------
  // Internal interface (extensible)
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to revert state when conditions are not met. Use super to concatenate validations.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _preValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    require(_beneficiary != address(0));
    require(_weiAmount != 0);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an executed purchase. Observe state and use revert statements to undo rollback when valid conditions are not met.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _postValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    // optional override
  }

  /**
   * @dev Source of tokens. Override this method to modify the way in which the crowdsale ultimately gets and sends its tokens.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be emitted
   */
  function _deliverTokens(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    token.transfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Executed when a purchase has been validated and is ready to be executed. Not necessarily emits/sends tokens.
   * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be purchased
   */
  function _processPurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    _deliverTokens(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Override for extensions that require an internal state to check for validity (current user contributions, etc.)
   * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _updatePurchasingState(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    // optional override
  }

  /**
   * @dev Override to extend the way in which ether is converted to tokens.
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei to be converted into tokens
   * @return Number of tokens that can be purchased with the specified _weiAmount
   */
  function _getTokenAmount(uint256 _weiAmount)
    internal view returns (uint256)
  {
    return _weiAmount.mul(rate);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
   */
  function _forwardFunds() internal {
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

browser/ERC20.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./ERC20Basic.sol";


/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender)
    public view returns (uint256);

  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value)
    public returns (bool);

  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(
    address indexed owner,
    address indexed spender,
    uint256 value
  );
}
```

browser/ERC20Basic.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine here. The problem must be in your setup or maybe you have typoed something.

I copypasted the code here, deployment works: https://ethfiddle.com/wx5-dGzkNc

Note that you haven't actually implemented the token itself at all, but I assume that's something you'll tackle next after you get this working. All you have done is import the abstract token contracts.